# filtering and sorting foreach loop by date (string) in php

Tags: php, loops

My question is a bit coufusing ,

I got events in my database
every event has it own start date and end date
so I created three tables

1. the first one is for open events
2. the second one is for not opened events
3. the last one is for closed events

So I want to create foreach loop for creating table rows and sort it by start date for the second one and  sort it by end date for the first and the last one

and thanks

my try :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>

            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        sort($rows);
        $u = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row) :
            $u++;
            $university = getUniversityByBsc($row['id']);
            if ($today < $row['date_end'] && $today > $row['date']) :
        ?>
                <tr>
                    .

                    .

                    .

                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        sort($rows);
        $u = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row) :
            $u++;
            $university = getUniversityByBsc($row['id']);
            if ($today > $row['date_end'] && $today > $row['date']) :
        ?>
                <tr>
                    .

                    .

                    .

                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        sort($rows);
        $u = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row) :
            $u++;
            $university = getUniversityByBsc($row['id']);
            if ($today < $row['date_end'] && $today < $row['date']) :
        ?>
                <tr>
                    .

                    .

                    .

                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            .

            .

            .

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: welcome to so, what have you tried so far

Comment: It seems like your structure is not optimal to begin with. Is there really a good reason why you have three separate tables? Do you have a lot of different data for these three statuses?

Comment: no I don't have structure but this type of events requires some separating

Comment: By table you mean 3 HTML tables not DB tables? You cannot use sort for your case. take a look at [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: yeah of course I mean 3 html table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your structure is array of associated arrays. To sort by key value, you need to provide your custom comparison function that takes two arrays then compare between them.

You can visit [Array Sorting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) to see all PHP sorting functions.

I believe you need to use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

In the documentation example, there is function that can help you to achieve what you need.

```
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}
```

This function will take a key as parameter, and it will return a comparison function that will compare the values associated with that key.

Copy the function to your code then use it to sort your array.

```
// This will sort the array based on start_date descending. 
usort($rows, build_sorter('start_date'));
// This will sort the array based on start_date descending. 
usort($rows, build_sorter('end_date'));
//Call the function before your table and sort the array as you which.
```

**Update:**

Here is sample code, please note when I wrote the code I used `start_date` and `end_date` as field name instead of `date_start` and `date_end`. Also please avoid using old PHP syntax.

```
<?php
 
//the function sorting function for usort
function build_sorter($key) {
    return function ($a, $b) use ($key) {
        return strnatcmp($a[$key], $b[$key]);
    };
}

//sample data
$rows = array(
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'start_date' => '2021-01-27',
        'end_date' => '2021-02-28'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'start_date' => '2020-01-28',
        'end_date' => '2020-02-28'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '3',
        'start_date' => '2020-01-01',
        'end_date' => '2020-01-10'
    ],
);

//Today dates as mentioned in the comments
$today = date('Y-m-d',time());


?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                id
            </td>
            <td>
                start date
            </td>
            <td>
                end date
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
//first table sort by end_date

usort($rows,build_sorter('end_date'));

//now your array is sorted you need to create the table
//for loop throw the rows to print and for filttering 
foreach ($rows as $row){
    if ($today < $row['end_date'] && $today > $row['start_date']){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['start_date']}</td><td>{$row['end_date']}</td><tr>";
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
   

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                id
            </td>
            <td>
                start date
            </td>
            <td>
                end date
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php

//second table sort by start_date

usort($rows,build_sorter('start_date'));

//now your array is sorted you need to create the table

//for loop throw the rows to print and for filttering 
foreach ($rows as $row){
    if ($today > $row['end_date'] && $today > $row['start_date']){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['start_date']}</td><td>{$row['end_date']}</td><tr>";
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>


<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                id
            </td>
            <td>
                start date
            </td>
            <td>
                end date
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php

//third table sort by end_date

usort($rows,build_sorter('end_date'));

//now your array is sorted you need to create the table

//for loop throw the rows to print and for filttering 
foreach ($rows as $row){
    if ($today < $row['end_date'] && $today < $row['start_date']){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['start_date']}</td><td>{$row['end_date']}</td><tr>";
    }
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you so much, but how can I separate it to three tables

Comment: @Eymen is $today a string or Date object, also is start_date string or Date object

Comment: `$today = date('Y-m-d');` start_date and end date is string contains date like `'2021-01-28'`

Comment: @Eymen I updated my answer with sample code.